# Solution to Chef and Squares challenge, timing out in Java but not in C++

Tags: java, c++, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded, comparative-review

I was solving a [problem on codechef](https://www.codechef.com/NOV16/problems/CHSQR) (online judge and contest organizer). I was writing my code in Java and was getting TLE at last testcase where as I wrote the same code in C++ and it was accepted. Now I know C++ is faster then java but If anyone could help me optimize my Java code ?

**Here is the question**

> Chef has finished his freshman year in college. As a present, his
>   parents gave him a new problem to solve: Chef has to fill a K x K
>   square grid of integers in a certain way. Let us say that such a grid
>   is valid if:
>
> - Each cell contains an integer from 1 and K (inclusive).
> - No integer appears twice in the same row or the same column.
>
> Let F(K) be maximum possible distance between the center of the square and the closest
>   cell that contains 1, among all possible squares with the side length
>   K.
>
> Here, we use the following notions:
>
> - The distance between cell (x, y) and (i, j) is equal to |x-i|+|y-j|.
> - The center of a K × K square is cell ((K+1)/2, (K+1)/2) for odd K.
>
> #### Input
>
> The first line of input contains a single integer T denoting the
>   number of test cases. Each test case consists of a single line
>   containing a single odd integer K.
>
> #### Output
>
> For each test case, print K lines each consisting of K space separated
>   integers giving some square grid where the distance from the center of
>   the grid to the nearest 1 is exactly F(K). If there's more than 1
>   possible answer output any of them.
>
> #### Constraints
>
> K<sub>i</sub> is odd.
>
> #### Subtask #1 (10 points):
>
> 1 ≤ T ≤ 50
>   1 ≤ K<sub>i</sub> ≤ 5
>
> #### Subtask #1 (90 points):
>
> 1 ≤ T ≤ 10
>   1 ≤ K<sub>i</sub> < 400
>
> #### Example
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> 2
> 1
> 3
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> 1
> 3 2 1
> 1 3 2
> 2 1 3
> ```

**Here is my code in Java**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {       
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader sc = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int t = Integer.parseInt(sc.readLine());
        while(t-- > 0){
            int n = Integer.parseInt(sc.readLine());        
            int center = (n + 1)/2 ;                
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                int temp = center;
                for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
                    System.out.print(temp+" "); 
                    temp++;
                    if(temp > n)
                        temp = 1;                                               
                }                   
                center--;
                if(center < 1)
                    center = n;
                System.out.printf("%n");
            }
        }    
    }   
}
```

**Here is my code in c++**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void){
    int t;
    cin>> t;
    while(t--){
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        int center = (n + 1)/2 ;                
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            int temp = center;
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
                cout<<temp<<" "; 
                temp++;
                if(temp > n)
                    temp = 1;                                               
            }                   
            center--;
            if(center < 1)
                center = n;
            cout<<"\n";
        }
   }    
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: add: `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);std::cin.tie(nullptr);` At the beginning of main() to make it go faster.

Comment: This works in java? I am getting a compilation error .

Comment: No: That is for C++

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To me the implementations look identical. But one thing jumps out at me:

If `n` is big then you will do a lot of string concatenations here: `System.out.print(temp+" ");` which may look inconspicuous but if n=399, then you will do around 160k useless string concatenations. Try to use a `StringBuilder` and build all your output into it and then dump it in one go when you're done. Or simply change to:

```
System.out.print(temp);
System.out.print(' ');
```

Also I think `System.out.format("%n");` is a bit odd why not simply do `System.out.println();`?

And `temp` is a really bad variable name. I suggest you change it.

Comment: I read on stackoverflow that `System.out.printf("%n);` is faster than `System.out.println();`. But I am not still sure about it.

Anyways thanks a lot for your answer! :)

Comment: Instead of printing everything I used `StringBuilder` and then kept on appending everything and then at last printed a single string and it managed to get accepted.
Finally I can sleep in peace .

Answer (score 9):

My first observation was the same as @EmilyL.'s: that you're performing unneeded string concatenations.  Upon investigation, however, it turned out to be a loser to substitute two invocations of `System.out.print()` methods for a string concatenation plus one method invocation -- the result ran about 70% slower than the original code for me.

It took a while for the lightbulb to turn on, but that slowdown is a key symptom of the underlying problem: `System.out` is unbuffered, at least when it's not connected to a terminal.  In a comment you described addressing the problem by building the output in a `StringBuilder` and then printing it all at once.  That's a viable mechanism for buffering manually, but cleaner and easier to integrate into your original solution would have been to wrap a buffered stream around `System.out` and print to that.  In other words, at the top of `main()` add ...

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(System.out));
```

... and everywhere else print to `out` instead of to `System.out()`.  Doing that cut my run time by more than 50% relative to the original code, for a maximal-size test set.

Comment: bonus: use `System.setOut(out)` ;) (and I could be wrong, but since you're in a BufferedOutputStream now, I think you'll have to call `System.out.flush()` at the end)

Comment: I was not aware that `System.out` is unbuffered. I learned something new today!

Comment: Using `PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(System.out));` the execution time is 0.36 sec whereas with `StringBuilder` and `System.out.print();` it 0.16 sec.
But Thank you for your answer, I learned something new today :)